# rendering volume the right way?

Tags: rendering, animation, lighting, volumetrics

So I am rendering some abstracts and I have never really rendered a scene with volume and I am noticing how much noise it can create. I have searched around but can't seem to find a smooth setup for how to render this locally with cycles.

[image]

Here is an image rendered at 1920x1080 with 300 samples

[image]

Here is that same image at 2880x1620 with 600 samples

So there is still a ton of noise and very little improvement even though the render time went up from 3 minutes to 15 minutes per frame...

It makes me think that when rendering volume I need specific settings for my tile size, denoiser, volumetrics, AO, etc ...

If anyone has any pointers it would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you all !!!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know much about volume rendering but you can check out https://youtu.be/kYv3ZIlb_sU this guys videos about nebulae and volume rendering with eevee (actually pretty good).